# How to set xlim in seaborn barplot?

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart

I have created a barplot for given days of the year and the number of people born on this given day (figure a). I want to set the x-axes in my seaborn barplot to `xlim = (0,365)` to show the whole year.
But, once I use `ax.set_xlim(0,365)` the bar plot is simply moved to the left (figure b).

[image: img]

This is the code:

```
#data
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['day'] = np.arange(41,200)
df['born'] = np.random.randn(159)*100

#plot
f, axes = plt.subplots(4, 4, figsize = (12,12))
ax = sns.barplot(df.day, df.born, data = df, hue = df.time, ax = axes[0,0], color = 'skyblue')
ax.get_xaxis().set_label_text('')
ax.set_xticklabels('')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_ylim(0,10e3)
ax.set_xlim(0,366)
ax.set_title('SE Africa')
```

How can I set the x-axes limits to day 0 and 365 without the bars being shifted to the left?

Comment: Does the issue persist if you specify `x` and `y` arguments as column names in [`sns.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html)?

Comment: I have tried to do: `ax = sns.barplot(x = df.day, y = df.born, data = df...`, and `ax = sns.barplot(x = 'day', y = 'born', data = df...` but I still get the same problem, yes.

Comment: Could you please share the data as well so that it becomes a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I added some data to it.

Comment: The data is like this; it only goes from day 41 to day 199. And that is exactly where my problem is. I want to set the `xlim` from 0 to 365 so the barplot gets centred and comparable to other African regions where I also set `xlim` from 0 to 365.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected output given the nature of data is difficult to obtain straightforwardly, because, as per the documentation of [seaborn.barplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

> This function always treats one of the variables as categorical and draws data at ordinal positions (0, 1, … n) on the relevant axis, even when the data has a numeric or date type.

This means the function `seaborn.barplot` creates categories based on the data in `x` (here, `df.day`) and they are linked to integers, starting from 0.

Therefore, it means even if we have data from day 41 onwards, seaborn is going to refer the starting category with `x = 0`, making for us difficult to tweak the lower limit of x-axis post function call.

The following code and corresponding plot clarifies what I explained above:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# data
rng = np.random.default_rng(101)
day = np.arange(41,200)
born = rng.integers(low=0, high=10e4, size=200-41)

df = pd.DataFrame({"day":day, "born":born})

# plot
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))

sns.barplot(data=df, x='day', y='born', ax=ax, color='b')
ax.set_xlim(0,365)
ax.set_xticks(ticks=np.arange(0, 365, 30), labels=np.arange(0, 365, 30))
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_title('SE Africa')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

I suggest using [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html) to overcome this issue, although handling colors of the bars would be not straightforward compared to `sns.barplot(..., hue=..., ...)` :

```
# plot
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))

ax.bar(x=df.day, height=df.born) # instead of sns.barplot
ax.get_xaxis().set_label_text('')
ax.set_xlim(0,365)
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_title('SE Africa')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]